# What's the insight for a 3x3 matrix with orthogonormal columns,the rows are also orthogonormal?

Tags: matrices

I know this can be easily proved with simple matrix tricks,

But I don't know the insight for this, and just feels it amazing that if I pick up 3 orthogonormal vectors in 3d space, their corresponding x,y,z portions automatically forms orthogonormal basis,too!

I've been googling a lot with no satisfactory answer, hope I can find it here,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A square  real matrix $M$  has columns ON if and only if $M^{-1}=^tM$ if and only if $(^tM)^{-1}=M=^t(^tM)$  if  and  only  if  $^tM$  columns are ON if and only if $M$ lines are ON.

ON = orthonormal.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

Imagine the simplest case, where the three vectors are:
$$(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$$
Clearly, if you take the transpose of these vector's matrix and construct new vectors, you get the same ones, which are of course orthogonal. Now, take any three orthogonal vectors - using a rotation, we can always get back to the three unit vectors.